# Why can't I find my custom UITextField class in Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitextfield

I created a custom class inherited from `UITextField`.

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

}
```

And the project already has another subclass called `DefaultTextField`.

Then I drag an `UITextField` from object library into my scene of `UIViewController`.When I try to set its custom class in Identity Inspector,the prompt dropdown does not show my custom class except for previously added `DefaultTextField`.

[image]

I tried to reopen or clean the Xcode project,nothing helps.My Xcode version is 6.3.2.Any helps?

Comment: @iphonic but I'm using Swift as project language.

Comment: Ah, yes sorry, it is swift, the cause may be `Indexing`, try clean your project. You just copy paste the Class `MyTextField` in place of Custom Class picker, it will work..

Comment: Ahha,I found a solution.The project structure has a directory,when moving MyTextField file into that directory,the problem solved.But I still don't know why.